# Create a new node in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed in my only serve elasticsearch 5.0 in debian 8.

Reading the [elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/_create_an_index.html), in the last paragraph:

> You might also notice that the customer index has a yellow health
>   tagged to it. Recall from our previous discussion that yellow means
>   that some replicas are not (yet) allocated. The reason this happens
>   for this index is because Elasticsearch by default created one replica
>   for this index. Since we only have one node running at the moment,
>   that one replica cannot yet be allocated (for high availability) until
>   a later point in time when another node joins the cluster. Once that
>   replica gets allocated onto a second node, the health status for this
>   index will turn to green.

Then my question: How I can create a new node for fix that?

Comment: You can start another node same way you start the first one. You might want to change a few configurations like the transport address.

Comment: i dont created any node, i just install ES in my server like that: `aptitude install elasticsearch`.